# Retrieving list of values from MYSQL data base based on input value(LARAVEL 10 )(GET HTTP METHOD)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, http

I am fairly new to PHP & laravel so looking for some assistance.

For example , i have a table in mySQL database that stores comments by a user. The values for this table are userId,bookId & Comment. I essentially want to build a function in my controller where it will retrieve a list of comments for a specific bookId. So if bookId 'cm123' has a total of 7 comments for that book , then my function should retreive all 7 comments with a HTTP GET request. This route is strictly going into the API route , we are not using any view for this ,so forms & such for input are not needed-- rather the parameters will be manually inputted when testing the request in Postman.

**Again , the end result i am aiming for is that the API returns a list of book comments stored in the database given a specific bookId input**

Below are my model , route & controller classes (I do already have a function for this called "SHOW" but it is not working) :

**Contoller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\CreateComment;
use App\Models\BookRating;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class BookRatingController extends Controller
{
    
  

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     */
    public function show(string $bookId): View
    {
        return view('CreateComment.Comment', [
            'Comment' => CreateComment::findOrFail($bookId)
        ]);
    } // return list of comments
```

**Model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CreateComment extends Model
{

    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable =
    [
        'Comment',
        'userId',
        'bookId'
    ];
}
```

**Route**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\BookRatingController;
use App\Http\Models\BookRating;
use App\Http\Models\CreateComment;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider and all of them will
| be assigned to the "api" middleware group. Make something great!
|
*/

Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::post('CreateRating',[BookRatingController::class, 'CreateRating']);//adding a bookrating to database API -- POST METHOD-- 
Route::post('CreateComment',[BookRatingController::class, 'CreateComment']);

Route::get('show/{$bookId}',[BookRatingController::class,'show']);
```

Comment: Is it producing a 404 status code ?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the above functionality first make the route as below in routes/api.php

```
use App\Http\Controllers\CommentController;

Route::get('comments/{bookId}', [CommentController::class, 'show']);
```

Then modify a below function in CommentController in show function

```
public function show(Request $request, string $bookId)
    {
        // Retrieve comments based on the provided bookId
        $comments = CreateComment::where('bookId', $bookId)->get();

        // Check if comments exist for the given bookId
        if ($comments->isEmpty()) {
            // Return appropriate response if no comments found
            return response()->json(['message' => 'No comments found for the specified bookId'], 404);
        }

        // Return comments as JSON response
        return response()->json($comments);
    }
```